# Scala converting recursively bounded type parameter (F-bounded) to type member

Tags: scala, types, parametric-polymorphism, type-members, bounded-quantification

How would I convert:

```
trait Foo[A <: Foo[A]]
```

to a type member?

I.e., I want something along the lines of the following:

```
trait Foo {
  type A <: Foo {type A = ???}
}
```

but I am having difficulty because the name A is already taken within the type refinement. This question is similar (and spawned from): [F-bounded quantification through type member instead of type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225582/f-bounded-quantification-through-type-member-instead-of-type-parameter/14232069)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a self-type:

```
scala> trait Foo { self => type A <: Foo {type A = self.A}}
defined trait Foo

scala> class Bar extends Foo { type A = Bar }
defined class Bar

scala> class Bar extends Foo { type A = Int }
<console>:10: error: overriding type A in trait Foo with bounds <: Foo{type A = Bar.this.A};
 type A has incompatible type
       class Bar extends Foo { type A = Int }
                                    ^
```

Comment: This was my original intuition, great answer!